# Compiling with both -g3 and -O3

Tags: debugging, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, build

Most build environments I've seen have at least two strategies: debug build vs final/optimized/release build. With gcc, this usually means some version of `-g` vs `-O`. Now I'm seeing a situation where the optimized build is built with `-O3` while the debug version is built with `-g3` *and* `-O3`. `man gcc` does indicate that is possible, but this seems counterintuitive to me for real debugging purposes.

Reviewing http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html reminded me of `-Og`, which allows optimizations that do not interfere with debugging. That makes sense to me, but what compelling reason is there to debug with `-O3 -g3` unless you are basically trying to debug gcc's own optimization abilities?

Comment: .. or if you're trying to debug the optimized code (which might have different bugs than the unoptimized code).  What exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is why the environment I'm looking at is compiling debug versions with `-O3 -g3`. I'm trying to figure out what information one can learn that one couldn't learn with just `-g3`. I vaguely know the answer, which you have also provided, but I'm looking for examples or further clarification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes people write bad code - maybe code that causes undefined behaviour, for example.  Now let's say that that undefined behaviour appears to work "correctly" in the case of low- or no optimizations, but that it causes a disastrous crash at `-O3`.  You're going to want to debug this problem at `-O3`, right?  So then you have no choice but to add a `-g` flag and go to town, even though the debugging experience might be somewhat compromised by optimizations.

There is a big problem in general with build systems conflating the "debug/release" axis with the "optimized/unoptimized" axis.  Really, they should be orthogonal - it's often desirable to have a "debug" build with logging, for example, but still have it run fast with optimizations enabled.  Similarly, it could potentially be very difficult to track down an optimizer-related bug without having debug symbols available in your optimized build.

```
                   +--------------------------------+
                   |           Optimizations        |
                   +-----------------+--------------+
                   |        On       |     Off      |
 +----------+------+-----------------+--------------+
 |          |  On  | Debug optimized |  Best debug  |
 |  Debug   |      |    code         |  experience  |
 | Logging/ +------+-----------------+--------------+
 | Symbols  |  Off |   Release build | Probably not |
 |          |      |  for customers  |    useful    |
 +----------+------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I mostly disagree with the recommendation that the Release build for customers should have debug symbols turned off in general. In fact Microsoft in MSVC has the default policy to produce symbols for both Debug/Release builds, and so is XCode. Only very restricted set of code (like hot paths code, or mathematical code that needs extreme optimizations) should have debug symbols turned off.

Comment: External symbols are fine, you just probably don't want to deliver your internal secret sauce to your customers. Unless open source or otherwise part of your business model, I guess.

Comment: Definitively, but deploying debug symbols doesn't reveal the source code and are often distributed as a mean to offer better debug experience (eg. Microsoft public symbol server)

Comment: I'll edit the chart to match what I said in the answer; that axis is supposed to include other debug niceties like logging/etc.

Comment: "Probably not useful" = "good for Valgrind runs on extremely annoying UB bugs"